# change font size of dateinput

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

How do you change the font size of a dateInput item

```
 dateInput("MyDate", "Date:", value = "2018-01-01"),
```

I am using

```
shinyUI(navbarPage(
                   tags$head(
                     tags$style(HTML("
                                     @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Cabin:400,700');

                                     .selectize-input { font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px;} 
                                     .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px; }
                                     .input-sm {font-size: 12px; } 

                                     "))
                     ),tabPanel("MyPanel",
                         column(1,
                                 wellPanel(


                                   dateInput("MyDate", "Date:", value = "2018-01-01"),
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, long time passed, maybe still someone will find it useful, I've managed to achieve the desired result using `tags$head` and `tags$style` and pointing to specific input by its `id`:

```
    tags$head(
     tags$style(HTML("#MyDate [type = 'text'] {fontsize:12px;height:14px;}"))
    )
```

Effectively, you are changing the format of the inputs, restricting the range of affected elements by pointing to a specific ID (`#MyDate`), thereby solving the problem that bk18 has mentioned.

I myself have just started exploring Shiny, so this might not be the most efficient/elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your tags, try:

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(
    ".form-control {font-size: 2em !important;}"
  )
)
```

This will make all the input text huge. The interesting thing is that the inputs all share the same class according to css, and changing the column container class doesn't seem to work. My answer above should work, but it won't be specific to the date input. I'll try to work it out, but in the meantime try the above!

Comment: Last time before I give up!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to change the `h_` label in the code, e.g `h1`,`h2`,`h3`....and so on.

```
dateInput("MyDate", label = h2("My Date"), format="mm-dd-yyyy",value = "2018- 
01-01")
```

You can also control `width=` in this argument as well

Comment: I am looking to change the size of the font of the dates not the label